# How to get displayed text from disable dropdown list?

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

how can i get visible value from disable dropdown list ?

Best Regards,
thank you

Comment: It would help if you posted the HTML source for the dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `selenium.getSelectedValue()` or `selenium.getSelectedLabel()`.  [Both are described here.](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.0/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/DefaultSelenium.html#getSelectedLabel%28java.lang.String%29)

If you have a dropdown list defined as follows:

```
<select name="dropdown" disabled>
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
  <option selected value="3">three</option>
  <option value="4">four</option>
</select>
```

Then you can use the following script to assert that the (disabled) selected label is 'three'.

```
String selectedLabel = selenium.getSelectedValue("name=dropdown");
assertEquals("three", selectedLabel);
```